# Php create cronjob via api script not working

Tags: php

I want to create a cronjob in direct admin panel with a script on my website

```
         <form action="http://serverip:2222/CMD_LOGIN" method="POST" 
        name="form">
        <input type=hidden name=referer value="/">
        <input type=hidden name=username value="username">
        <input type=hidden name=password value="password">
        </form>
         <script>
         document.form.submit();
         </script>
```

Login is working.
But how can i add the cronjob? I tried it with no Luck.

Cronjob api direct admin http://www.directadmin.com/features.php?id=364

```
           GET or POST
           action=create
            minute=cron value
            command=/home/username/pathtorun
```

What must i edit in the login form to create cronjob?

This i what i tried

```
     <form action="http://serverip:2222/CMD_API_CRON_JOBS" method="POST" 
    name="form">
    <input type=hidden name=referer value="/">
    <input type=hidden name=username value="username">
    <input type=hidden name=password value="password">
    <input type=hidden name=action value="create">
    <input type=hidden name=minute value="2">

    </form>

     <script>
     document.form.submit();
     </script>
```

Result: no login / nothing else

Comment: Could you post what you have tried so far?

Comment: May be there is a permission problem.

Comment: @Chris i updated the post. Thanks.

Comment: @AlBundy that could be. How to fix?

Comment: First, check if this is really the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think I want to achieve the same thing as you, and I have just achieved it in less then 30 minutes by using httpsocket.php which you can download from the official Directadmin-website.

I had two problems which I had to solve:

1. Use ssl:// instead of http://
2. Use your webhosting domainname instead of your own domainname.

Sample script (just to view the existing cron jobs) looks like:

```
include 'httpsocket.php';

$sock = new HTTPSocket;

$sock->connect('ssl://$DOMAINOFWEBSERVER$',2222);
$sock->set_login('$LOGIN$','$PASSWORD$');

// $sock->set_method('POST');

$sock->query('/CMD_API_CRON_JOBS');
$result = $sock->fetch_parsed_body();

print_r($result);
```

To add a cron job, simply replace it with this:

```
include 'httpsocket.php';

$sock = new HTTPSocket;

$sock->connect('ssl://$DOMAINOFWEBSERVER$',2222);
$sock->set_login('$LOGIN$','$PASSWORD$');

$sock->set_method('POST');

$sock->query('/CMD_API_CRON_JOBS',
        array(
                'action' => 'create',
                'minute' => "1",
                'hour' => "12",
                'dayofmonth' => "*",
                'month' => "*",
                'dayofweek' => "*",
                'command' => "/home/username/pathtorun"
    ));


$result = $sock->fetch_parsed_body();

print_r($result);
```